# How to set 2d CDT to alow interception of constraints?

Tags: constraints, eclipse-cdt, cgal, terrain

I´m changing a 2D CDT terrain from constraints that don´t intercept to constraints that can intercept.

I changed:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> CDT;
```

to

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel EK;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<EK,TDS,Itag> CDT;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT> CDTP;
```

and all:

```
typedef typedef CDT::<...>
```

to

```
typedef CDTP::<...>
```

When I use the class Point to get the coordinates of a point for example:

```
  bool operator()(const Point & p1, const Point & p2) const
  {
    double x = p1.x();   //<--- Error on this line
    ...
  }
```

The compiler is issuing the error:

*there is no convertion from CGAL::Lazy_exact_ntboost::multiprecision::mpq_rational to double*

I did a reserch on this issue but had no success to fix this error.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Itag` is the parameter that is controlling the behavior of the code if constraints are intersecting (see the [doc](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__triangulation__2.html)). So if you have a working code without intersection using EPICK, changing `Itag` to `Exact_predicates_tag` is the only change needed.